# Temporal Tables - Is there a built in way of determining rows that have changed for a range of dates

Tags: sql-server, temporal-tables

It doesn't appear that Temporal tables offers a built-in way of determining all the rows that have changed during a period of time. The BETWEEN clause returns all rows active during a range of dates, but I'm looking for a way of determining all rows that have changed during a range of dates.

Comment: CONTAINED IN (<start_date_time> , <end_date_time>)

Comment: @TapakahUa - I don't think CONTAINED does what I'm looking for. For a row to appear in CONTAINED, it must be opened and closed within the time period. It will ignore any row that was opened and not closed. I want all rows that were opened and/or closed in a time range.

Comment: Can you qualify your query to say "start_time between interval_start and interval end or end_time between interval_start and interval_end"? That is, if either (or both) of the endpoints for the record are in the interval of interest, they were modified within that interval.